# Merge two .txt files together and reorder

Tags: bash

I have two .txt files both 42 lines each (42nd line is just a blank space).

One file is called date.txt, and each line has a format like:

```
2017-03-16 10:45:32.175 UTC
```

The second file is called version, and each line has a format like:

```
1.2.3.10
```

Is there a way to merge the two files together so that the date is appended to the version number (separated by a space). So the 1st line of each file is merged together, then the second line, third line, etc...

So it would look like:

```
1.2.3.10 2017-03-16 10:45:32.175 UTC
```

After that, is it possible to reorder the new file by the date and time? (Going from the oldest date to the latest/current one).

The end file should still be 42 lines long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`paste`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)):

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt -d' ' > result.txt
```

`-d` is used to set the delimiter.

You can then attempt to sort by second and third column using `sort`:

```
sort -k2,3 result.txt > sorted.txt
```

`-k` is used to select columns to sort by.

But note that this doesn't parse the date and time, only sorts them as strings.

In general:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | sort -k2,3 > result.txt
```

Comment: this will use tab as the delimiter, add `-d' '`

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. How would I then reorder the file by date and time?

Comment: try `sort -k2,3 result.txt > sorted`, but it will sort based on the string value, it won't parse the date and time.

Comment: You don't need to parse the date/time, because they're already in ISO-8601-style format, they will sort correctly anyway. However, the first field will not sort correctly if the numbers go above single digits.